# DHTMLX - Grid multiselection with smart rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, dhtmlx

I'm using a dhtmlx-grid and have a problem in the following use case.

I enabled multiple selection and the grid uses smart rendering to load a large set of data.
After the initial load, I select the first row in the grid, and then drag down the scrollbar to the last row and shift-click the last row.

The expected behavior is that all the rows in the grid should be selected, but this isn't the case.
The not-rendered-rows in between are not selected.

Glad if somebody can suggest me some good solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, only the rendered rows can be selected, so in case of enabled smart rendering mode you cannot implement the described steps. The only solution is to disable the smart rendering mode.